# One unnecessary turn in TicTacToe game

Tags: java

I'm trying to make this code for a TicTacToe game in JavaFX. But now even when there is a winner (meaning someone put his three Xs or Os in a row/column/diagonal) the programme still allows the other player to put his sign on the board. Only after that the winning buttons are changed and the buttons are set disabled. How do I change that?

```
package tictactoe;

import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class TicTacToeController {
private boolean isFirstPlayer = true;

public void buttonClickHandler(ActionEvent evt) { 
    this.find3InARow();  

    Button clickedButton = (Button) evt.getTarget();
    String buttonLabel = clickedButton.getText();

    if ("".equals(buttonLabel) && isFirstPlayer){
        clickedButton.setText("X");
        isFirstPlayer = false;
    } else if("".equals(buttonLabel) && !isFirstPlayer) {
        clickedButton.setText("O");
        isFirstPlayer = true;
    }

}
@FXML Button b1; 
@FXML Button b2;
@FXML Button b3;
@FXML Button b4;
@FXML Button b5;
@FXML Button b6;
@FXML Button b7;
@FXML Button b8;
@FXML Button b9;   
@FXML GridPane gameBoard;
@FXML MenuItem Play; 

private boolean find3InARow() {
    if (""!=b1.getText() && b1.getText() == b2.getText() 
        && b2.getText() == b3.getText()){
        highlightWinningCombo(b1,b2,b3);
        return true; 
    }

    if (""!=b4.getText() && b4.getText() == b5.getText() 
        && b5.getText() == b6.getText()){
        highlightWinningCombo(b4,b5,b6);
        return true; 
    }

    if (""!=b7.getText() && b7.getText() == b8.getText() 
        && b8.getText() == b9.getText()){
        highlightWinningCombo(b7,b8,b9);
        return true; 
    }

    if (""!=b1.getText() && b1.getText() == b4.getText() 
        && b4.getText() == b7.getText()){
        highlightWinningCombo(b1,b4,b7);
        return true; 
    }

    if (""!=b2.getText() && b2.getText() == b5.getText() 
        && b5.getText() == b8.getText()){
        highlightWinningCombo(b2,b5,b8);
        return true; 
    }

    if (""!=b3.getText() && b3.getText() == b6.getText() 
        && b6.getText() == b9.getText()){
        highlightWinningCombo(b3,b6,b9);
        return true; 
    }

    if (""!=b1.getText() && b1.getText() == b5.getText() 
        && b5.getText() == b9.getText()){
        highlightWinningCombo(b1,b5,b9);
        return true; 
    }

    if (""!=b3.getText() && b3.getText() == b5.getText() 
        && b5.getText() == b7.getText()){
        highlightWinningCombo(b3,b5,b7);
        return true; 
    }
    return false;

    }

    private void highlightWinningCombo(Button first, Button second, Button third) {
        gameBoard.setDisable(true);
        first.getStyleClass().add("winning-button");
        second.getStyleClass().add("winning-button");
        third.getStyleClass().add("winning-button");
    }

    public void menuClickHandler(ActionEvent evt){
        MenuItem clickedMenu = (MenuItem) evt.getTarget();
        String menuLabel = clickedMenu.getText();

        if ("Play".equals(menuLabel)){ 
            ObservableList<Node> buttons =  gameBoard.getChildren(); 
gameBoard.setDisable(false);

            buttons.forEach(btn -> { 
                ((Button) btn).setText("");  
                btn.getStyleClass().remove("winning-button");
            });
            isFirstPlayer = true;  
        }
        else if("Quit".equals(menuLabel)) {
            System.exit(0);
   }

    }
```

}

Comment: run the program with the debugger to check where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking the board before setting the last input by the player, so if the player has made a winning move, it will only be set once you have checked the winning conditions, so the program doesn't know if the last player has won. TO fix this, you first need to process the input, and then check for winning condition. To do that, simply move `this.find3InARow();`  to the end of the method `buttonClickHandler()`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It did help!